# Logout in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

Fails to implement the user `logout`.

Here is the code. I'm trying to run from the command line
`curl -d "" POST http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/users/settings/logout/`

But in response I get a `401 error - {"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}`. Although the user is logged in.

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
def logout(self, request):
    print(999)       #Nothing
    try:
        print(request.user.auth_token)
        request.user.auth_token.delete()
    except (AttributeError):
        pass
    from django.contrib.auth import logout
    logout(request)

    return Response({"success": _("Successfully logged out.")},
                    status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

It seems that the function does not even work ...

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication
from rest_framework import exceptions

from .utils import provide_user_to_sentry


class UserIdAuthenticateMixin:

    def authenticate_credentials(self, payload):
        """
        Returns an active user that matches the payload's user id.
        """
        User = get_user_model()
        user_id = payload.get('user_id')

        if not user_id:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid payload.')

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid signature.')

        if not user.is_active:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('User account is disabled.')

        return user


class JSONWebTokenSentryAuthentication(UserIdAuthenticateMixin, JSONWebTokenAuthentication):
    """Wrapper around ``JSONWebTokenAuthentication``

    In case of successful authentication it reports user id and IP address to sentry for later logging

    Clients should authenticate by passing the token key in the "Authorization"
    HTTP header, prepended with the string specified in the setting
    `JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX`. For example:

        Authorization: JWT eyJhbGciOiAiSFMyNTYiLCAidHlwIj
    """
    def authenticate(self, request):
        original_response = super().authenticate(request)
        if original_response is None:
            return original_response

        user, _jwt = original_response
        provide_user_to_sentry(request, user)
        return original_response


class UserIdJSONWebTokenAuthentication(UserIdAuthenticateMixin, JSONWebTokenAuthentication):
    """Wrapper around ``JSONWebTokenAuthentication``

    Update authenticate_credentials to check user id.

    Clients should authenticate by passing the token key in the "Authorization"
    HTTP header, prepended with the string specified in the setting
    `JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX`. For example:

        Authorization: JWT eyJhbGciOiAiSFMyNTYiLCAidHlwIj
    """
    pass
```

Comment: You're making a curl request from the command line. So what does it mean to say "the user is logged in"? What user? You don't have a user.

Comment: Sry. Entered and got a `token`. How can I to logout using `drf`?

Comment: Well, to logout, you need to be logged in. As the error clearly states, you need to pass a valid token in the request so that Django can authenticates you and fill `request.user`.

Comment: @frankie567 I tried with `curl -H "Authorization: JWT Token" POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/users/logout/' -H "X-CSRFToken:123" -b "csrftoken:123" `

Comment: Could you provide your `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` then? By default on DRF, it's rather `Authorization: Token xxxxxxx`.

Comment: Updated my code

Comment: You have quite a bunch of authentication classes there. Which method did you use to log in the first place?

Comment: @frankie567 always I get `500` error ` The view django.contrib.auth.logout didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: Well, if you use JWT authentication, you don't need a "logout". It's only useful if you use default `TokenAuthentication` where token is stored in database and you wish to delete it. In the case of a JWT, all the information is contained within itself, plus it will expire after a defined amount of time. `django.contrib.auth.logout` is also useless in an API context because it's only there to flush the session.

Comment: In this task need to implement. There is a front written on the `angular`, there is a lot of logic there - including user signin, token generation and logout. But need to pull the api when exiting and go out on the backend.

Comment: Logout on the Angular side can be as simple as removing your JWT token from the local storage. No need to call the server.

Comment: Thnx for help..

Comment: @frankie567 see my answer pls

Answer (score 2):

**Authorization**

After this request I get token for user

```
curl -H "Authorization: JWT Token" -d "email=test@gmail.com&password=password" POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/users/login/'
```

**Logout view**

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
def logout(self, request):
    try:
        request.user.auth_token.delete()
    except (AttributeError, ObjectDoesNotExist):
        pass

    django_logout(request)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Logout request**

```
curl -d "" -H "Authorization: JWT Token" POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/users/settings/logout/'
```

Comment: Ok, your controller works but believe me, it actually doesn't do anything. Since you use a JWT, there is no `auth_token` to delete. So you are passing by the `except` block. As for the Django `logout` function, it just [flushes the session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.logout). So unless you actually plan to use `TokenAuthentication` and `SessionAuthentication`, you don't need that view.